# UV unwrapping and texture issues

Tags: texturing, uv

I have a mode of a bathroom closet, and there is something wrong with the UV. I marked the seams, pressed "unwrap", but the checker texture look stretched for some reason.
[image]

And then I tried separating one of the doors and the checker texture changed, but I didn't touch the UV:

[image]

Then I got to the UV editor, and tried to scale and rotate the UV, but it didn't change how the checker texture look on the model:

[image]

[image]

And for some reason, when I try to look at an image texture, the UV editor is a rectangle and not square:
[image]

How can I solve it?

Comment: What do you mean connect the uv texture? How do I use the texture coordinate node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to connect your UV map to the *Checker Texture*.
Use *Texture coordinate* node for that.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. It looks better now.
https://i.imgur.com/kYAXX5i.jpg

Is it something I need to do every time I bring a new texture?
Do I  have metallic and roughness maps, do I need to plug the coordinate node to those maps as well, or is it enough to plug it just into the base color?

Comment: Hey :). Procedural textures (checker, voronoi, etc.) use *Generated coordinates* by default, so you need to plug your UV Map. Image textures (roughness, metallic) use the UV map automatically.